# Connected metric space and the compactness of $X\setminus\{x\}$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

**Problem:** Let $X$ be a connected nonempty metric space. Show that either $X$ consist of a single point or $X\setminus\{x\}$ is not compact for any point $x\in X$.

*Solution*. If $X$ consist of a single point then $X\setminus\{x\}=\emptyset$ is compact. For the other part let $|X|>1$. By way of contradiction, suppose $X\setminus\{x\}\neq\emptyset$ were compact for some $x\in X$. Since $X$ is a metric space, it is Hausdorff. As points are closed in a Hausdorff space, $X\setminus\{x\}$ is open. On the other hand, compact subsets of Hausdorff spaces are closed, so $X\setminus\{x\}$ is closed. Therefore $X\setminus\{x\}$ is a nontrivial "clopen". A contradiction to $X$ be connected.

---

My first question: is the above correct? If so, can this problem just be reduced to talking about Hausdorff spaces instead of metric spaces...?

Comment: It seems correct to me and  the Hausdorff condition seems to be sufficient too. The thing is if you have the metric space condition you can do the not compact proof similar to proving that $(0,1]$ isn't compact, this relies on less knowledge, but is more technical and i would say your proof is more elegant anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As linkja indicated in the comments, your proof is perfectly fine, and you even proved the more general result:

> If $X$ is a connected Hausdorff space with at least two points, $X\setminus\{x\}$ is not compact for any point of $x\in X$.

Note that we cannot weaken the Hausdorff hypothesis to $T_1$.  For example, if you take an infinite set $X$ with the [cofinite topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofinite_topology), the [resulting space](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000015/properties) is $T_1$ and connected (it's even hyperconnected).  But every subspace of $X$ is compact in this case, as its induced topology is also a cofinite topology.